# 429 request cannot be determined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, rest

[image]

[image]

My First Image is my network -> headers

My Second Image is my console

The situation is trying to log-in with incorrect credentials about 15-20 times

What I want to achieve is be able to determine In my client which is AngularJS if I have a response status of 429.. I did a:

```
console.log(response)
```

on the second image but I can not determine on my client side if I received a 429 status request

```
function(response){
    var res_data = (response.data && response.data.data) ? response.data.data : null;
    var res_status = response.status;
    FlashService.Error(response[keys.issue_fields], true);
    console.log(response);
    console.log("----");
    if (res_status == 513 && res_data && res_data[keys.issue_fields][0] == keys.email) {
        vm.error = "Your email is not recognized. Please try again.";
    } else if (res_status == 513 && res_data && res_data[keys.issue_fields][0] == keys.password){
        vm.error = "Your email and password combination was incorrect. Please try again.";
    } else if (res_status == 513 && res_data && res_data[keys.issue_fields][0] == keys.suspension){
        vm.error = "Your account is inactive.";
    }else if (res_status == -1) {
        vm.error = "Error connecting to server.";
    }else if(res_status == 429){
        vm.error = "You have attempted a numerous login failed attempt.. Please try again later.";
    }else {
        vm.error = "Your email and password combination was incorrect. Please try again.";
    }
    vm.dataLoading = false;
    }
```

**PS**

The code should work fine, it's just I cant get the response code at all

Comment: How are you using this `function(response) {...}`?

Comment: I am using that to catch an error response from my error log-in attempts